# I want to fill a 2d array using pointer and scanf

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[20][20];

    char (*p)[20];
    p = arr;
    
        
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            scanf("%s", *(*(p+x)+y));
        }
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            printf("%s",x,y, *(*(p+x)+y));
        }
    }
```

I'm wanting the user to be able to fill an array using scanf and pointer. I want it to use pointer because I will use the same code later so that the user can change a 2d array inside a struct

when I try to run the program and enter the first information it closes by itself[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYnob.png)

Comment: You know you can dereference the pointer by subscripting? `p[y][x]`

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I don't even know what that means. I'm doing this for a school project. I already programmed a little before but the concept of pointers is new to me. English is not my native language so, despite being able to read the text in English, many tutorials on the internet are confusing

Comment: If `p` is `char(*p)[20] = arr;` and you do `p[0]` it'll point at the first `char[20]` in `arr`. `p[1]` will point at the second `char[20]` in `arr`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/9xzazPhd1)

Comment: The error you are getting is `C0000005` memory access violation error. Check out the (several) compiler warnings. The argument for `scanf` is the wrong type, and for the `printf` there are 3 arguments where 1 is expected.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument expression in this call

```
scanf("%s", *(*(p+x)+y));
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

has the type `char` but due to the used conversion specifier `s` the function expects an argument of the type `char *`. As a result the program has undefined behavior.

And to enter strings you need only one for loop.

If you want to enter character by character instead of entering a string then the loops can look the following way using pointers

```
for ( char ( *row )[20] = p; row != p + 3; ++row )
{
    for ( char *item = *row; item != *row + sizeof( *row ); ++item )
    {
        scanf( " %c", item );
    }
}

for ( char ( *row )[20] = p; row != p + 3; ++row )
{
    for ( char *item = *row; item != *row + sizeof( *row ); ++item )
    {
        printf( "%c", *item );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf( " %c", item );
       ^^^^
```

It allows to skip white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'`.

If to enter strings in the array then the loops can look like

```
for ( char ( *row )[20] = p; row != p + 3; ++row )
{
    scanf( "%19s", *row );
}

for ( char ( *row )[20] = p; row != p + 3; ++row )
{
        printf( "%s\n", *row );
}
```